# Spoilers in user profiles don't show permanently once they are clicked, unlike for posts

Tags: bug, profile-page, spoilers

When mousing over spoiler markup, the text underneath it shows temporarily, disappearing when you move your mouse cursor away from it.

Additionally, you can click it to make it keep showing even after you move your mouse away (a second click will hide it again).

To demonstrate, here's some example spoiler text:

> Clicking this text should make it continue to show even after you move your mouse away.

While this clicking behavior works fine in posts, this doesn't seem to work in user profiles. Here's an [example profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/412159/eleeza-the-character-wizard?tab=profile) which contains spoiler markup to demonstrate this issue; unlike the spoiler text above, clicking the spoiler text in the profile will *not* make it continue to show after the mouse is moved away.

It appears that user profiles use an older, forked version of the CSS (e.g. link titles are still not underlined despite them being changed to be so in posts recently), and the clicking behavior hasn't made it there yet.

Reproduced in Google Chrome stable (version 79). This may not be reproducible in mobile browsers, since many of them implement a behavior whereby tapping a specific element will make the page *think* the "cursor" is always on top of it, masking out the effects of this bug. It can definitely be reproduced in a desktop browser on a non-touchscreen machine.

Comment: It seems permanent on responsive mobile (Safari).

Comment: @Stormblessed Mobile browsers retain the virtual "cursor" wherever you tap, so as to allow pages coded for desktop browsers to have some usability. The fact that it "works" in Mobile Safari is because the website thinks your cursor is still on it.

Comment: Non- repro for Android mobile (responsive)

Comment: @curious See comment above.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog For what it's worth, I got the same behavior as you with 64-bit FireFox 71.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Reproduced with Firefox 70.0.1 on Mac OS 10.11.6.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your example question and example profile using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 and in both cases:

- when I mouseover the spoiler it appears
- when I move mouse away from the spoiler it disappears

Then when I test clicking the spoiler and moving away:

- for the example question it stays
- for the example profile it disappears

Consequently, this appears to be a problem in that web browser too.