# Different font sizes in mobile site and responsive website on mobile

Tags: feature-request, support, design, mobile-web

This is how post looks in responsive design on mobile

[image]

And that's how in mobile site

[image]

The font on responsive design looks as small as what subscript and superscript fonts used to look like. Can we have little bigger fonts?

I'm using Firefox on Android 10.

Comment: I'd repost this as an answer to the announcement, as those tend to be more likely to be noticed by the team.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Looks like someone have already [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353554/468333).

Comment: Voting to reopen this since the answer in question did not exist at the time this question was posted. While it is better to file these as answers to the announcement, they shouldn't be closed as duplicates unless the answer *already existed* at the time the question was posted; if the answer was posted *later*, then that would be an ex-post-facto duplicate closure, which is against community norms.