# No italics on mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

This is what [this post](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/22792/how-to-translate-unscratchable-itch-to-russian) looks like on a desktop browser (Windows 10, Chrome 84.0.4147.135):

[image]

This is what it looks like on a mobile browser (Android 8, Firefox 79.0.5):

[image]

Italic text is not formatted on the mobile.

Comment: Already reported here: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353544/289905).

Comment: @user289905: is it some kind of canonic post where people report bugs?

Comment: It’s common practice to report bugs and feature requests for recent changes directly under the announcement post.

Comment: On FF Android [when "Desktop Site" is chosen italics are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVSKY.jpg), when that is disabled so are italics.