# "Reveal spoiler" text is hidden when hover over on a spoiler in revision history

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, revisions-list, spoilers

With the new formatting, in the revision history when hovering over on a spoiler, the "Reveal spoiler" text is hidden, but whereas in the normal post when hovering over on a spoiler, the "Reveal spoiler" text is not hidden. It seems that inconsistent in the user interface.

[Sample Revision Post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/52093/revisions)

**GIF image from the revision history:**

[image: Revision]

**GIF image from the post:**

[image: Post]

Comment: This reminds me of the joke programming that causes objects you try to click to move away from the mouse pointer as soon as you hover over them.

Comment: This is *almost* a duplicate of a [report on the new formatting post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353528/395497), but there's another distinct issue being reported here, so I'm not marking as duplicate. That being said, the fix for the other will fix this one as well. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Strange. Earlier, spoilers in revisions looked like this, [with some overlapping text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s65uF.png). And now, in addition, if a specific revision is hidden first and you click on the arrow for it to be shown, or if you click to hide, then click to show it again, [the spoiler is just empty altogether, including when hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg6lZ.png). A click will still reveal it.

Comment: Now you can't hide a spoiler once revealed, except by reloading the page. Sometimes I like a quick peek without wanting to see the whole post. IMO a better algorithm would be reveal on hover, after say 2 seconds, because it was too reactive before, and hide immediately after moving the mouse away. They are fixing things that are not broken.

Comment: This has been fixed as of the latest round of spoiler fixes. I just missed updating this post at that time. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly The “Reveal spoiler” label is still missing in revisions when you expand them (i.e. when they were previously collapsed, as well as when you collapse and expand an already expanded revision). Should there be a separate feature request post for this issue?

Comment: @user289905 Oh drats, you're right. I did not notice that one. It should probably be its own report, but I'll take a look either way. I'll upvote and tag your post if you end up creating one and link it here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed as of the latest round of spoiler fixes. I just missed updating this post at that time. Thanks for the report!