# Hyperlinks in code formatting no longer follows site color

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, code-formatting

Earlier [`code`](https://example.com) used to follow site colors, for example,

Orange on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)<sup>[Click on image to open corresponding cached page/post]</sup>
:

[image: Orange on AU]

and blue on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

[image: Blue on U&L]

But now they no longer follow site colors.

This is how it looks now on Ask Ubuntu:

[image: This is how it looks now on AU]

And this is how it looks now on Unix & Linux:

[image: This is how it looks now on U&L]

Comment: Related: [Links with inline code formatting look weird.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353534/289905).