# Unable to differentiate between code and hyperlinks with code formatting on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, markdown, mobile-web, code-formatting

This is a follow up of my earlier question [Hyperlinks in code formatting no longer follows site color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353663/468333).

The links in code formatting on mobile site aren't underlined which worsens the above situation and make it difficult to differentiate between `code` and [`code`](https://example.com) on mobile site.

This is how I see the above line on mobile site:

[image: Is the second one a link or what?]

Can we have at least an underline, If not site colors on the above said formatting for now?

Comment: @user289905 no it's not related. If it's a joke, it's hard to get the joke.

Comment: Workaround is to browse the full site on the mobile device, there is limited support for responsive design, and hopefully within few years everything will be responsive. Until then, guess they won't remove the mobile theme, so better also make it useable.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask The question is about links in code spans not having an underline, thus being impossible to distinguish, especially since the color is lost with the latest design changes. The linked question is about the underlying issue that links are not underlined on the mobile site. I tried to find a more recent feature request that points out that the full site has underlined links, but the mobile site doesn’t — if you can find one, that’d be nice to link here.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Sites, by default, in mobile phones, opens as mobile site. It takes more clicks to get responsive design. I'd be happy to see responsive design as default on mobiles too.

Comment: Now also reported here: [Links around code don't show up on the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353947/289905).

Comment: Cross-site post on MSO: [Code links not distinguished on iPhone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402164/4642212).