# What have you done to the scrollbars of code blocks? The buttons are missing

Tags: bug

Code blocks have a scrollbar but the arrow buttons are missing at both ends. There's just a grey gap. The thumbtrack doesn't reach to the ends but leaves the space for the buttons.

I have found two CSS rules that can be disabled to fix this. So it looks like this has been done either on purpose (strange purpose) or in a failed effort to achieve something else. It's not new, must have been like that for several weeks now. It certainly looked correctly longer ago.

(Firefox on Windows, affects all SE sites)

**Update:** Yes, it's been reported before. I've just added this to my existing SE user style and I'm happy again. Let's see what other places are still missing.

```css
/* Restore scrollbar design, uglified intentionally */
/* See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353858/144124 */
pre,
.s-prose pre:not(.s-code-block),
pre.s-code-block,
.s-input, .s-textarea
{
    scrollbar-color: unset;
}
```

I noticed that the scrollbars look differently in Chrome/Windows. They have a similar appearance to Android (which I find inappropriate on a desktop, but at least it's not as broken as in Firefox).

Comment: could you give an example of a post with this issue for folks who are curious?

Comment: This appears to have been already reported, and is by design: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353524/622284

Comment: @Spevacus Yeah...It shouldn't be though:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting/353524#comment1181413_353524, I totally agree with that.

Comment: I don't care if they want to get rid of the buttons, but leaving a gap where they used to be is not good. What's the point? It just makes me thing the scrolling is broken because it isn't scrolling all the way left or right.

Comment: Some background: Only Firefox supports the `scrollbar-color` property - we do nothing to the scrollbar in any other browser because it's not supported by any other browser. The arrows disappearing are not *intentional* but seem to be a side-effect of Firefox's implementation of `scrollbar-color` (it stops using standard theming altogether, which drops the arrows, the moment you start using `scrollbar-color`). I'd say it makes little sense to use it given it's only supported by one browser and is broken in that one browser. (I also don't like when websites theme the scrollbar at all.)

Comment: And even less sense given that it doesn't change *anything* except removing the buttons. I mean, this isn't even a compromise, it's only losing, no win. Whoever has designed this has done a very poor job. An immediate revert would be appropriate.

Comment: @ygoe SE does theme the scrollbar more than just dropping the buttons (e.g. the scrollbars are thinner) (or at least they did the last time I looked, but I overrode that CSS almost immediately after SE started using it, so I don't know what it's doing now).

Comment: @Makyen Maybe in Chrome. In Firefox, my main browser, nothing else is visible than the missing buttons. Not even the colours look noticeably different.

Comment: @ygoe I have made a [feature-request requesting it's reversal.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354392/please-make-ask-question-page-scroll-buttons-visible-again)

Comment: @Ollie I don't know what that is, so you'll have to try out yourself. I'm using Stylus.

Comment: @ygoe Tried it, and also TylerH's Stylus solutions.  They work well, thank you.