# Please make scrollbar arrows visible again

Tags: feature-request, design, firefox

In my Firefox 81.0.1 64-bit, on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, the scroll buttons in the Similar Questions list on the Ask Question page (and also in code blocks everywhere else) are invisible:

[image]

That scrollbar wouldn't go up any further.  I wondered about this, and @JohnDvorak [explained](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8562268#8562268) that the buttons are invisible, and that it [was by design](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8562274#8562274), which is confirmed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353524/798831).  This also happens with the question body when there is enough content to merit a scrollbar.

With due respect, it is a terrible design choice to make a button that is functioning and clickable invisible.  Can we please revert this?

---

**UPDATE**

@TylerH's [Stylus solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354545/798831) works very well.  Codeblock scrollbars:

[image]

And the scrollbar-buttons in the question body:

[image]

@Ygoe's [solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353858/798831) (it too is Stylus) should also be noted.  Both do the job, and are very simple fixes.  Thanks Tyler, Ygoe!

Comment: I provided some background for what is happening [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353858/what-have-you-done-to-the-scrollbars-of-code-blocks-the-buttons-are-missing). It absolutely was not our design choice to have blank space where the arrows should be. It is a side-effect of attempting to color the scrollbar. If anything, it was Firefox's design choice.

Comment: @animuson How is it the vendor's fault that you are using styles which cause this problem? I'm not buying that... just don't use non-standard properties and the problem goes away.

Comment: @TylerH First off, it is a standard property that is part of a CSS working draft, and second the standard gives the vendor control over what happens when the color is changed. Which honestly makes it not very standard in my opinion. As I said in the other question, I hate when websites customize the scrollbar. I believe the browser should be the sole controller over what the scrollbar looks like and the website should not be messing with it. I hope when this property is more worked out that browsers will have the option to disable it across all sites, but that's just me.

Comment: @animuson I thought it was the -moz-scrollbar-color style that was causing the issue. Maybe I'm remembering the vendor-specific styles that apply to Chrome instead.

Comment: But how about SE not messing around with the scrollbar, @animuson? That would fix things right?

Comment: @Luuklag It would, and I'm all for it. But it's not my decision.

Comment: @animuson any chance to make this status-review and have the design team have a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a stopgap measure, per Ollie's request, I'm posting a Stylus user style here to fix this, at least for Firefox:

```css
/* reverts scrollbar to normal browser behavior */
pre:not(.CodeMirror-line) {
    scrollbar-color: var(--scrollbar) !important;
}
```

In Stylus, make sure this applies to "URls on the domain" of the following values:

- `stackoverflow.com`
- `stackexchange.com`
- `superuser.com`
- `mathoverflow.net`
- `serverfault.com`

to hit all the various SE sites that are on their own domains.

Comment: @Ollie No it does not. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @Ollie Are you on Windows or macOS? I'm on 80.0.1 on Firefox, but nothing related to this changed in 81. Try also adding a style like `* { color: red !important; }` to the user style document that applies to the pages to make sure it is taking place. That would turn all text red. If it doesn't turn everything red then you have something else conflicting, don't have live preview turned on/haven't saved it correctly/enabled it correctly, or don't have the right URL settings.

Comment: @Ollie Remove the `@` query. The add-on and styles are per-browser already. Here is what my styles look like (some additional styles currently lumped into that selector for other changes) and what domains they apply to below (the "what domain this applies to" below each code block applies to the code block above it). If you don't get the option to apply the "URLs on the domain" option you may need to uninstall and reinstall the add-on. FWIW I am on version 1.5.13 of Stylus (Aug 10, 2020).

Comment: @Ollie Not sure, as I don't think I've seen that on the site before. Do you have an example question that has a scrollbar inside it that isn't for a code block I can test on?

Comment: Yahoo!  [Got it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKzDR.png)  Thanks for all your help, Tyler, it looks way better now ;)

Comment: Accepting this answer for now to give it more visibility.  SE doesn't look like it'll get to this any time soon, but for now, this is great.