# Unable to view spoiler text in post timeline

Tags: bug, timeline, spoilers

A [sample post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting?noredirect=1&lq=1); it has a spoiler near the end.  But when you look in the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/353446/timeline), and see the latest edit, you can't see the spoiler text, "reveal spoiler", or reveal the hidden text beyond by clicking on it.  Can we fix that, please?